# Can I reap (or do something other than "fight") with the Gauntlet of Command?

Tags: keyforge

Consider the situation: I have a single creature and my opponent does not have any. I want to use the Gauntlet of Command on my creature: "Ready and fight with a friendly creature". But there is nothing to fight with. So can I ready my creature and reap (or do some other action) with it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reap with a creature after readying it with Gauntlet of Command if there are no enemy creatures available to fight with.

Keyforge has a general rule to "**Resolve As Much As You Can**". So in this case, activating Gauntlet of Command tries to:

- Ready the chosen creature (If the creature is already ready, this fails to happen but the ability still continues resolving),
- then forces the chosen creature to fight (If there are no targets available, the fight fails and the creature remains in a Ready state).

You may then do whatever you can normally do with a Ready creature.

Comment: You're right, but maybe important to note that if the creature is not from your chosen house, you can't use it. For example: if you chose Brobnar you could use the Gauntlet on a Logos creature to ready it and fight with it when there is a target, but if there is no target, the Logos creature is ready, but can't reap or use its action.

Comment: I considered mentioning it, but decided to just go for the blanket statement in the last paragraph. That should also cover not just reaping, but also any special creature actions available or board-wide effects etc...